# Como hacer una busqueda en un arbol de k dimensiones (KDTree)

Tags: java

tengo un arbol 2 dimensiones y su estructura es la siguiente:

```
public class KDNodo{
   int x;
   int y;
   KDNodo left;
   KDNodo rigth;
}
public KDTree{
    KDNodo root;
}
```

Hay que tener en los niveles impares se coge la x y que los nodos que tienen valores inferiores a x se ponen a la izquierda y los que tienen valores superiores o iguales a la derecha.

En los niveles pares se hace lo mismo pero con la y.

Alguien puede ponerme un ejemplo de una busqueda? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo bien la configuración de tu árbol, pero si lo tomo literal haría estos métodos para insertar:

```
public class KDTree{
    KDNodo root;


    public void insertaNodo(KDNodo nodo) {
        if (nodo == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (root == null) {
            root = nodo;
        }
        else {
            insertaParEn(nodo, root);
        }
    }

public void insertaParEn(KDNodo nuevo, KDNodo actual) {
    if (nuevo.x < actual.x) {
        if (actual.left == null) {
            actual.left = nuevo;
        }
        else {
            insertaInparEn(nuevo, actual.left);
        }
    }
    else if (actual.rigth == null) {
        actual.rigth = nuevo;
    }
    else {
        insertaInparEn(nuevo, actual.rigth);
    }
}

public void insertaInparEn(KDNodo nuevo, KDNodo actual) {
    if (nuevo.y < actual.y) {
        if (actual.left == null) {
            actual.left = nuevo;
        }
        else {
            insertaParEn(nuevo, actual.left);
        }
    }
    else if (actual.rigth == null) {
        actual.rigth = nuevo;
    }
    else {
        insertaParEn(nuevo, actual.rigth);
    }
}
```